# Para que serve o tipo "application/ld+json" em uma tag <script>?

Tags: html, json, script

Estava olhando o código fonte da página do Kickass e este trecho me chamou a atenção:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "https://kat.cr",
   "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "https://kat.cr/usearch/{q}/",
      "query-input": {
        "@type": "PropertyValueSpecification",
        "valueRequired": true,
        "valueName": "q"
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Isso é algum definições de algum framework e/ou biblioteca? Qual o propósito de usar `type="application/ld+json"` em uma tag script? O que pode ser feito com isto?

Comment: Para o eventual navegante que quer saber como acessar esse objeto facilmente, [tem no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602543/is-there-a-way-to-access-json-ld-via-javascript-if-it-doesnt-have-an-id)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#embedding-json-ld-in-html-documents) é um dos vários tipos de Schema, assim como o [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)), ele não faz nada pro javascript ou pro HTML em si, na verdade ele é usado por buscadores, como o Google, ele é um "padrão de dados" que você usa pra instruir os buscadores pro tipo de conteúdo que o site oferece ou como é a organização das páginas, o nome disto é "marcação de dados estruturados" (Structured Data Markup).

Buscadores são inteligentes pra detectar o conteúdo, navegação e funcionalidades do site, mas não o suficiente, pois ninguém escreve HTML do mesmo jeito, a solução encontrada foi criar métodos de organizar os dados, assim os buscadores podem identificar e até personalizar o resultado da paginação, como por exemplo:

- <kbd>[image: *]</kbd>

Veja tem o preço o rating e as reviews pra cada resultado, os buscadores as vezes conseguem fazer isso por si só com o seu site, mas nem sempre é possível.

Um exemplo de navegação:

- <kbd>[image: *]</kbd>

Existem outros tipos de dados que foram propostos pelo http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html como:

- [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) exemplo:

  Veja esta é a informação sobre uma pessoa, mas os buscadores provavelmente não entenderão tão bem:

  ```
  <section> Hello, my name is John Doe, I am a graduate research assistant at
  the University of Dreams.
  My friends call me Johnny. 
  You can visit my homepage at <a href="http://www.JohnnyD.com">www.JohnnyD.com</a>.
  I live at 1234 Peach Drive, Warner Robins, Georgia.</section>
  ```

  Agora com Microdata, desta maneira você usa html normal e ainda explica pro buscador as informações da pessoa:

  ```
  <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> 
      Hello, my name is 
      <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>, 
      I am a 
      <span itemprop="jobTitle">graduate research assistant</span> 
      at the 
      <span itemprop="affiliation">University of Dreams</span>. 
      My friends call me 
      <span itemprop="additionalName">Johnny</span>. 
      You can visit my homepage at 
      <a href="http://www.JohnnyD.com" itemprop="url">www.JohnnyD.com</a>. 
      <section itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
          I live at 
          <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Peach Drive</span>,
          <span itemprop="addressLocality">Warner Robins</span>,
          <span itemprop="addressRegion">Georgia</span>.
      </section>
  </section>
  ```
- [RDFa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) exemplo:

  Usando RDFa pra explicar pro buscador as informações de uma pessoa:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>John's Home Page</title>
      <base href="http://example.org/john-d/" />
      <meta property="dc:creator" content="Jonathan Doe" />
      <link rel="foaf:primaryTopic" href="http://example.org/john-d/#me" />
    </head>
    <body about="http://example.org/john-d/#me">
      <h1>John's Home Page</h1>
      <p>My name is <span property="foaf:nick">John D</span> and I like
        <a href="http://www.neubauten.org/" rel="foaf:interest"
          xml:lang="de">Einstürzende Neubauten</a>.
      </p>
      <p>
        My <span rel="foaf:interest" resource="urn:ISBN:0752820907">favorite
        book is the inspiring <span about="urn:ISBN:0752820907"><cite
        property="dc:title">Weaving the Web</cite> by
        <span property="dc:creator">Tim Berners-Lee</span></span></span>.
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

O problema do RDFa e do Microdata é que tem que usar HTML5+xml, isto mistura o html com os "esquemas", atrapalha um pouco, por isso o JSON-LD pode ser mais fácil de implementar, pois os dados ficam em uma tag separada, como descrever uma pessoa:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name",
    "homepage": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/workplaceHomepage",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "Person": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"
  },
  "@id": "http://me.example.com",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Smith",
  "homepage": "http://www.example.com/"
}
```

Leia mais em: http://schema.org/docs/gs.html

### Navegação (Breadcrumbs)

Nem só de informações de pessoas é feito os "Dados estruturados" (Structured Data), a algum tempo os sites como Mercadolivre e Uol veem usando a navegação assim com Microdata:

> Home > Produtos > Informática > Computador Dell i5

Este é um bom motivo pra usar o Json e "ensinar" aos buscadores como funciona a navegação do seu site, exemplos:

- JSON-LD:

  ```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/arts",
        "name": "Arts"
      }
    },{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/arts/books",
        "name": "Books"
      }
    },{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 3,
      "item": {
        "@id": "https://example.com/arts/books/poetry",
        "name": "Poetry"
      }
    }]
  }
  </script>
  ```
- RDFa:

  ```
  <ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
    <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
      <a property="item" typeof="WebPage"
          href="https://example.com/arts">
        <span property="name">Arts</span></a>
      <meta property="position" content="1">
    </li>
    ›
    <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
      <a property="item" typeof="WebPage"
          href="https://example.com/arts/books">
        <span property="name">Books</span></a>
      <meta property="position" content="2">
    </li>
    ›
    <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
      <a property="item" typeof="WebPage"
          href="https://example.com/arts/books/poetry">
        <span property="name">Poetry</span></a>
      <meta property="position" content="3">
    </li>
  </ol>
  ```

### Testando

O Google fornece uma ferramenta de teste https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ que suporta URLs ou digitar no campo de texto, pra validar a sua marcação.

### Criando rapidamente a sua própria marcação

O google tem uma ferramente que auxilia a rápida criação dos dados estruturados:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/

---

> <sup>**Nota:**</sup>
>
> Não me lembro ao certo, mas acho que 2 anos atrás o Google incentivava fortemente o Microdata na documentação, notei que muitos sites rapidamente se adaptaram a este formato, mas agora na documentação parece incentivar o JSON-LD fortemente e o RDFa