# Uso dos atributos itemid e itemref nos elementos da HTML5?

Tags: html5

Gostaria de entender o correto funcionamento semântico dos atributos microdata itemid e itemref nos elementos da HTML5. Obrigada!

Comment: Entendo sua boa intenção, mas recomendo que pesquise antes quando for fazer uma nova pergunta, existem várias respostas já no site, o nosso buscador é bem avançado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching ;)

Comment: Editei para melhorar o foco da pergunta. Obrigada! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já foi explicado aqui [Para que serve o tipo "application/ld+json" em uma tag <script>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117153/para-que-serve-o-tipo-application-ldjson-em-uma-tag-script) este é fundamento do Microdata, RDFa e JSON-LD, eles servem pra facilitar os crawlers a extraírem os dados e proporcionarem melhor experiencia ao usuário nos resultados de buscas (claro que provavelmente eles podem vir a servir pra outras finalidades, vai depender de quem ou de que ferramenta tiver interesse nesses dados).

> Resumindo eles ensinam o seu site a falar :)

Já no microdata os atributos:

- `itemscope` - cria o item e indica que os descendentes desse elemento conter informações sobre ele.
- `itemtype` - Deve conter uma URL válida que descreva o item e seu contexto propriedades.
- `itemid` - Deve conter um identificador único do item.
- `itemprop` - Indica que a sua tag contendo mantém o valor da propriedade do item especificado. Nome e valor de contexto da propriedade são descritos por vocabulário do item. Valores de propriedades geralmente consistem em valores de cadeia, mas também pode usar URLs usando o elemento e seu atributo href, o elemento img e seu atributo src, ou outros elementos que apontam para recursos externos ou incorporar.
- `itemref` - propriedades que não são descendentes do elemento com o atributo `itemscope` pode ser associado com o item usando este atributo. Fornece uma lista de ids de elemento (não de item id) com propriedades adicionais em outras partes do documento.

O microdata pode ser usado para descrever várias coisas, portanto existe várias maneiras de descrever algo, por exemplo quer descrever uma pessoa:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> 
    Hello, my name is 
    <span itemprop="name">John Doe</span>, 
    I am a 
    <span itemprop="jobTitle">graduate research assistant</span> 
    at the 
    <span itemprop="affiliation">University of Dreams</span>. 
    My friends call me 
    <span itemprop="additionalName">Johnny</span>. 
    You can visit my homepage at 
    <a href="http://www.JohnnyD.com" itemprop="url">www.JohnnyD.com</a>. 
    <section itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        I live at 
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Peach Drive</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Warner Robins</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Georgia</span>.
    </section>
</section>
```

> No entanto recomendo usar json-ld, pois além de evitar obstruir o HTML irá ajustar na manutenção e organização sem misturar os dados.