# Quais são os atributos existentes na tag html?

Tags: html5

Na HTML5, quais são os atributos possíveis que podem ser utilizados no **elemento** (tag) `html`? Eu sempre aprendi os atributos estudando pelo [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp), mas percebi que nada dizem sobre atributos como `prefix` e `xml:lang` e até outros simples como `alt` e `disabled`, entre outros que devem existir que ainda não conheço. Obrigada!

Comment: disabled na tag <html>?? Qual seria a utilidade disso?

Comment: Tem alguns [atributos comuns a qualquer elemento](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes). O elemento `html` tem apenas [um atributo específico adicional](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) - que até o momento eu nem sabia que existia.

Comment: @DiegoF realmente não vejo utilidade, como muitos outros atributos. Sou defensora do fim dos atributos sem explicação de existência. Mas se eles existem, um dia podem aparecer em algum código. Acredito que você já tinha conhecimento que ele existia. Mas, e quando nos deparamos com atributos que nunca vimos? Sempre que olho um código vejo um atributo que nos estudam não apareciam.. :( Não é nem pelo uso, mas pela vontade de saber que existem... obrigada.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas a pergunta é para saber somente os atributos possíveis no elemento (tag) html e não em todos os elementos possíveis na HTML5.

Comment: Eu tinha entendido errado, desculpe. Nesse caso não é ampla mesmo. A resposta mais confiável está na especificação do HTML, mantida pelo W3C (que não tem relação com a w3schools, embora muita gente caia nessa).

Comment: Editei meu primeiro comentário, acrescentando um link a mais

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ### W3C != W3Schools
>
> Primeiro gostaria de citar, que é uma coisa muito comum pra quem começa a estudar e fazer perguntas no google, o W3Schools não tem ligação alguma com o W3C ou W3.org, eles só usam o nome semelhante pra dizer que ensinam coisas que contém no W3C, mas isso não quer dizer que eles ensinam corretamente ou apenas HTML/CSS/XML.
>
> O W3Schools também ficou conhecido pelas inúmeras falhas nos seus exemplos e  tutoriais, além de explicações equivocadas sobre algumas tecnologias
>
> Hoje podemos dizer que a maioria dos erros no W3Schools foram corrigidos, mas não quer dizer que ele seja oficial ou que tenha bons exemplos
>
> - [MDN (en-US)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)
> - [W3C (en)](https://www.w3.org)

Sobre os atributos suportados pela tag `<html>`, não é porque um atributo é incorreto em uma tag que ele não irá funcionar, tecnologias como HTML, JavaScript e CSS funcionam de maneira semelhante em todos navegadores atuais, mas não quer dizer que foi o W3.org que as implementou, por exemplo não é porque o w3c lançou o HTML5 que ele vai funcionar de maneira igual em todos navegadores, o W3C é apenas uma espécie de "regulamentador" (quem padroniza as tecnologias) pra evitar que comecem a surgir muitas diferenças entre os navegadores o que dificultaria os desenvolvimento de sites (isso já ocorreu no passado as famosas Browser wars, que vai além de quem é o mais usado, por que um navegador queria ser melhor que o outro criavam tecnologias que não eram standards, então isso gerou muita dor de cabeça).

Como eu citei em um comentário, você não precisa saber o A,B,C do funcionamento de algo, mas busca-lo no momento de necessidade. A única utilidade que vejo pra aprender quais são todos atributos suportados por uma tag é se você:

- Vai criar um Crawler
- Vai criar uma biblioteca JavaScript que manipula o DOM pra algum objetivo muito especifico

Se não for bem isso, ou melhor se for apenas criar páginas pra navegar em navegadores convencionais, então se apegue em fazer o básico e intermediário, se necessitar de algo avançado como OpenGraph do Facebook então pode aplicar normalmente, não se preocupe sites grandes como eles não iriam criar um "esquema" de HTML/XML falho, isso "queimaria o filme deles".

Existe o uso do *Microdata* ou *RDFa* que por vez podem obstruir o HTML se falhar em algum momento na digitação (erro humano) e por este motivo foi criado o JSON-LD, como citei aqui: [Para que serve o tipo "application/ld+json" em uma tag <script>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117153/3635) Mas se fizer com cuidado e atenção ainda sim poderá conseguir fazer sem obstruir o código, quero dizer use algo quando necessário, não há muitos motivos pra entender a **interface** a fundo.

O link https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html leva pra este https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html

**Core:**

> `accesskey`, `class`, `contenteditable`, `contextmenu`, `dir`, `draggable`, `dropzone`, `copy`, `move`, `link`, `hidden`, `id`, `lang`, `spellcheck`, `style`, `tabindex`, `title` e `translate`

**Eventos:**

> `onabort`, `onblur`, `oncanplay`, `oncanplaythrough`, `onchange`, `onclick`, `oncontextmenu`, `ondblclick`, `ondrag`, `ondragend`, `ondragenter`, `ondragleave`, `ondragover`, `ondragstart`, `ondrop`, `ondurationchange`, `onemptied`, `onended`, `onerror`, `onfocus`, `oninput`, `oninvalid`, `onkeydown`, `onkeypress`, `onkeyup`, `onload`, `onloadeddata`, `onloadedmetadata`, `onloadstart`, `onmousedown`, `onmousemove`, `onmouseout`, `onmouseover`, `onmouseup`, `onmousewheel`, `onpause`, `onplay`, `onplaying`, `onprogress`, `onratechange`, `onreadystatechange`, `onreset`, `onscroll`, `onseeked`, `onseeking`, `onselect`, `onshow`, `onstalled`, `onsubmit`, `onsuspend`, `ontimeupdate`, `onvolumechange` e `onwaiting`

**XML:**

> `xml:lang`, `xml:space` e `xml:base`

Mas devo lembrar, **não** é porque o atributo `oncanplaythrough` esta listado é que ele vai funcionar e **não** é porque o atributo `disabled` **não** esta listado que não irá funcionar (é bem provável que funcione), o funcionamento em cada navegador pode ocorrer de maneira totalmente diferente de outro (apesar que hoje a maioria esta funcionando bem padronizado), mas não é porque o navegador suporta algo que este uso é valido conforme a padronização.

Em resumo *padrão*  é uma coisa, *funcionar* é outra. No entanto eu prefiro sempre tentar seguir o máximo o padrão e em raras ocasiões faço o uso de algum *hack* (como o caso comum no CSS) que não é padrão pra ajudar a atingir um objetivo, muitas vezes por carência de alguma funcionalidade em um determinado navegador.

Comment: Detalhe: você não linkou para a especificação, e sim para um documento com recomendações de uso do html. Ali parece ter pelo menos um atributo a mais (contextmenu).

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que entendi, vou terminar uma outra resposta e volto pra editar esta =)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu vi seu outro comentário, a especificação seria esta: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes ?

Comment: Eu entendo que sim. O problema é que hoje em dia as especificações não são muito estáveis, são constantemente atualizadas.

Comment: @bfavaretto A sim, mas acho que foi perto disso que eu quis (tentei ao menos) dizer com a resposta, não é porque algo esta listado ali que vai funcionar, ou porque não esta listado que não vai funcionar. Acho que o ponto que eu queria chegar era este: *você não precisa saber o A,B,C do funcionamento de algo, mas busca-lo no momento de necessidade. A única utilidade que vejo pra aprender quais são todos atributos suportados por uma tag é se você: - Vai criar um Crawler -
Vai criar uma biblioteca Javascript que manipula o DOM pra algum objetivo muito especifico*...

Comment: @bfavaretto ... eu removi a parte "o que é suportado na tag HTML" e deixei apenas como referencia. Mas se achar que ainda tem algo errado por favor me oriente. Obrigado =)

Comment: Eu não concordo com esse ponto aonde você quer chegar (talvez porque eu goste de conhecer as coisas em detalhes), mas a resposta é boa mesmo assim :)

Comment: @bfavaretto eu também gosto de conhecer em detalhes =) Mas hoje eu estou costumando a medir o custo de tempo, levando em consideração que algumas coisas no HTML5 que seriam implementadas foram removidas antes do HTML5 se tornar padrão, alguns navegadores chegaram a implementar funcionalidades que logo em seguida foram removidas do standard do w3 :/ - Ae que eu o digo, não vejo muita utilidade em conhecer as "interfaces" a fundo a não ser que você esteja: Desenvolvendo um motor de renderização, Crawler, ou uma ferramenta de manipulação DOM pra algo especifico =) -- Mas obrigado pelo apoio

Comment: Eu adorei a resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento, ele conseguiu absorver bem a necessidade da pergunta. Mas no meu ponto de vista que sou uma pessoa que está começando os estudos, deixar passar o A,B,C.. até pode dar velocidade em aprender as utilidades mais relevantes, mas ao mesmo deixo de conhecer algo que poderá ser importante mais à frente e talvez nem saiba que A,B,C, existem... e o dia que precisar usar algo que nunca tive conhecimento antes posso acabar gerando "gambiarras". Por isso, nessa parte, concordo com o bfavaretto. Mas Guilherme você é um super herói para mim.. muito obrigada! :)

Comment: @IngridFarabulini Obrigado =) fico feliz com seu comentário. O que quero dizer ainda com a resposta é que se manter no básico e estudar conforme vai implementar algo avançado, por isso citei o *"então se apegue em fazer o básico e intermediário"*. Você também é uma heroína, pois diferente de muitos você prefere procurar o caminho certo mesmo que seja mais difícil, parabéns!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigada pelas palavras, é verdade, acredito que se pelo menos mais desenvolvedores tivessem esse interesse de fazer o que é certo, teríamos um mundo tecnológico "não mais chato", mas mais coerente e menos deprimente. =)

Comment: Confirmando a informação de o W3Schools não é afiliado ao W3C, no [about do W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/about/default.asp) está escrito: *...W3Schools was created in 1998, and derives its name from the World Wide Web (WWW) but is not affiliated with the W3C....* ou em português *...W3Schools foi criado em 1998 e seu nome deriva da World Wide Web (WWW), mas não é afiliado ao W3C....*