# Como usar keywords no google atualmente?

Tags: google, seo

O meu site já está indexado pelo google, porém ele não busca pelo nome do site, ele só busca se eu digitar www.minhaempresa.com.br mas se eu digitar apenas minhaempresa, ele não acha... e eu já coloquei a meta tag keyword e não funcionou alguém pode me dar uma luz ?

Comment: Autoridade e relevância vc só ganha com o tempo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vai ser da noite pro dia, não vai ser ter meta tags em seu site que vai fazer ele ficar na frente, isso nem é um problema de programação e nem de HTML.

SEO é de "investimento" (indireto), paciência e o quanto outros sites e pessoas buscam o teu site, não tem receita mágica, não tem receita de bolo e se alguém afirma que vai fazer você chegar em primeiro ou é porque vai ter um baita trabalho de meses ou porque estarão usando de estratégias blackhat e greyhat, e assim o seu site terá grandes chances de ser penalizado, mas não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso, é tudo muito amplo e não se domina da noite pro dia, nem em um ano geralmente se domina o assunto, é algo que demanda experiência séria.

---

### META tag keywords

Falando exclusivamente da tag `<meta name="keywords">`, ela não influencia mais no seu ranking, a muitos anos atrás (muitos mesmo) até tinha relevância, mas era tão mal usada que acabava atrapalhando, ou usávamos com má intenção ou simplesmente quem criava as páginas colocava as mesmas keywords em todas páginas, sem apresentar qualquer sentido pra navegação do usuário vindo de buscadores, era apenas confusão.

A tag hoje não serve de nada, hoje o buscador se baseia de fato no conteúdo e você pode melhorar o entendimento para os "indexadores" usando um destes:

- https://json-ld.org/ (a documentação google diz que este é preferível e com certeza é mais fácil de aplicar sem precisar mexer no layout do seu site)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/

---

### JSON-LD, Microdados/Microdata e RDFa

**Reforço duas coisas**:

- Não adianta colocar uma série de JSON-LD de qualquer jeito em todas páginas, tem que ser algo que explique bem o conteúdo de página a página
- Não vai melhorar teu ranqueamento, o que vai fazer é ajudar os buscadores a entenderem teu site e isso pode influenciar em outros fatores que este sim ranqueiam, mas ele diretamente não será o responsável pela melhora

Por fim teste a marcação acesse: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Mais detalhes sobre JSON-LD e outros (com exemplos) em:

- [Para que serve o tipo “application/ld+json” em uma tag `<script>`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117155/3635)